# How to make GTalkService Connection in android?

Tags: android, google-talk

Now i make the GTalkService Connection.And i have some info regarding this [check here](http://jon.oberheide.org/blog/2010/06/28/a-peek-inside-the-gtalkservice-connection/)

But how to start this GTalkService Connection application?

Answer (score 0):

try this: http://www.blizzhackers.cc/viewtopic.php?f=72&t=486999